# Entity Framework Working With Dynamic Table Names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, code-first

I created a database infrastructure with EF code-first like this:

- Main_Table1
- Main_Table2
- Sub_XX_Table1
- Sub_XX_Table2

I want `XX` to be filled from the logged-in user (and Entity Framework should create tables automatically if they do not exist).

Is that possible?

I tried to use `TableAttribute`, but that does not work, and is throwing a database changed exception instead:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DynamicTableAttribute : TableAttribute
{
    private TabloTuru _tabloTuru;

    public DynamicTableAttribute(string tableName, TabloTuru tabloTuru)
        : base(string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}",
            "RD",
            tabloTuru == TabloTuru.Donem ? 2.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "_" : string.Empty,
            tableName))
    {
        _tabloTuru = tabloTuru;
    }
}
```

Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Could you maybe explain why you think you need this? Having users create ad-hoc tables could be a very bad idea, but what is your use-case? The actual solution may simply lie in your data model...

Comment: Actually it wont be change for users. It will change for years. Manger wants to split data for years. User can be open 'new year tables' or access them. I cant 'change' this structure. I must 'make' what they want